# Знак препинания в предложениях типа "хорош (,) не то слово"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

В художественной литературе в предложениях типа "хорош (,) не то слово" можно встретить как запятую, так и тире, а также вовсе отсутствие какого бы то ни было знака. Многим авторам нравится тире. Так какой же знак препинания является нормативным в подобных предложениях?

Например:
— Да, Филдинг писал, что обстановка здесь сложная.    — Сложная — не то слово.
[Андрей Лазарчук. Священный месяц Ринь (1988)]

Comment: Немного исправил. Скобки с запятой нужно писать с пробелом, как в примерах отсюда: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=182.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ИСТОЧНИКИ по теме**

1. **[Значение пословиц и поговорок](https://znachenie-poslovic.ru/ne-to-slovo%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC)**

“Не то слово” является **выражением**, которое используется для обозначения **высшей степени** признака. Эта фраза обычно подчеркивает, что доступные слова и выражения не в состоянии полностью передать **качество** того, что описывается.

2. **[Справочник по пунктуации](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=490)**

**Частица (в ответной реплике)**. То же, что 'еще бы, конечно, слабо сказано'. Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми или тире, или оформляется как отдельное предложение.

*'Говорят, покойный был негодяем?' – 'Не то слово, не то слово...'* С. Довлатов, Компромисс. *'Ну как, устал?' – 'Не то слово, вымотался!'*

**Члены предложения**. Не требуют постановки знаков препинания.
*Нет, 'мерзко' не то слово.* В. Набоков, Лолита. *Я знаю, как называется эта вещь, но это не то слово, которое я слышал от Феди.*

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

Итак, в справочнике предлагается отсутствие знака как **основной** вариант. Но это **не соответствует** практике письма. По Нацкорпусу  самым частотным знаком является **тире**, реже можно увидеть отсутствие знака и запятую.

**1. Ставится тире** (самый частотный знак)

***Хорош** — не то слово*.

Рассмотрим тему **[Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)** в правилах Розенталя.

Как правило, тире **ставится**: 1) в предложениях, имеющих характер **логического** определения: *Геометрия — отдел математики, изучающий пространственные формы и отношения тел.*

Обычно тире **не ставится**: 3) если перед сказуемым стоит **отрицание НЕ:** *Офицер этот не чета вам* (Фед.); *…Уссурийский тигр совсем не сказка, явь почти* (Март.); *Бедность не порок* (Погов.); *Сердце не камень* (Погов.); *Аналогия не доказательство.*

**Постановка тире в этом случае** имеет целью логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое: *Но объяснение — не оправдание* (М. Г.); *Его взгляды на семейный этикет — не предрассудок ли это?*

**Тогда получаем**: *Слово "хорош" — не то слово, которое подходит в этом случае.* В сокращенном варианте: ***Хорош** — не то слово*.

**2. Нет знака**

***Хорош** не то слово.*

Опять же по Розенталю мы **можем не ставить** тире, если логического выделения нет. Вариант менее частотный, но применяется.

**3. Ставится запятая**

***Хорош,** не то слово.*

Такие примеры в Нацкорпусе еще поискать надо. Возможно, он удобен как **разговорный** вариант для замены тире, когда пауза есть, но ее можно обозначить **запятой**.

**ПРАКТИКА ПИСЬМА**

**1. Тире**

Пауза, два ударения.

Андрей Геласимов. Фокс Малдер похож на свинью (2001).
*Но интересно было, конечно. **ИнтерЕсно** — не то слОво.*

Д. А. Гранин. Месяц вверх ногами (1966).
*Он не дослушал меня. **НедовЕрие** — не то слОво. Он воспринял новость как глуповатую шутку.*

**2. Нет знака**

Пауза не обозначена. Обычно в тех случаях, когда текст на данной фразе не заканчивается. Одно ударение в конце предложения.

Анатолий Гладилин. Лодочник // «Октябрь», 2013.
***Претензия** не то слОво, и их к вам практически не было.*

Александр Иличевский. Перс (2009).
— *А ты как думал. **Особенное** не то слОво. Кандован — родина хлеба, оттуда пшеница пошла.*

Полина Волошина, Евгений Кульков. Маруся (2009).
*Представьте, если бы вы вдруг стали видеть, нет, **видеть** не то слОво, но, тем не менее, самое близкое по смыслу.*

**3. Запятая**

Пауза обозначена, но не подчеркнута. Два ударения.

Олег Павлов. Карагандинские девятины, или Повесть последних дней // «Октябрь», 2001.
*Пистолет был в кобуре. **СИлища,** не то слОво! Хочешь — казни, хочешь — милуй, прямо как Бог для других.*

Comment: Спасибо вам!!  За правку и за понимание...

Comment: Спасибо. Как всегда, глубочайшее погружение в тему.)

Comment: Иван, спасибо за оценку. А я очень довольна вашим вопросом. Сначала я рассчитывала на более легкий ответ (как бы недооценила вопрос), но встретились определенные трудности) Так что перестраиваться пришлось на ходу, чтобы хотя как-то "погрузиться" в тему))

Comment: "Погрузиться" - не то слово!)

Comment: У меня вот ещё какой вопрос. Требуется ли брать в кавычки первое слово, если его говорит уже другой человек?

Comment: @Иван Романов  Найти закономерность в использовании  кавычек довольно сложно.  Они могут применяться как в диалоге, так и в собственных рассуждениях. Кавычки  здесь скорее авторский выделительный знак, но никакой обязательности  нет. Вот примеры.  КАВЫЧКИ. Я не считаю, что смогла покорить Москву. «Покорить» — не то слово. // Нынче попрошайки Христа ради встречаются исключительно в городах. И даже «встречаются» — не то слово. — Дотянем, товарищ генерал, — заверил я. — «Дотянем» — не то слово, — заметил Рыбалко.

Comment: НЕТ КАВЫЧЕК.  А почему именно там? Особенное место? — А ты как думал. Особенное не то слово. Кандован — родина хлеба, оттуда пшеница пошла. //  Вы думаете, я потом не ругал себя? — Голос Павла внезапно охрип. — Ругал — не то слово…// — Ну да, вроде бы неплохо… Неплохо — это не то слово.

Answer (score 1):

Самым, наверное, правильным вариантом будет запятая. Так честно, скажу, я не знаю почему, но я очень часто полагаюсь на своё эстетичное видение и оно мне говорит "запятая лучший вариант"!

Comment: Можно посмотреть тексты, в том числе художественные, и увидеть, что варианты действительно есть. Так почему же   запятая — лучший вариант?

Comment: @Sharon Возможно, авторский выбор зависит от длительности паузы, но это не точно.) А может быть, от наличия или отсутствия слова "это".

Comment: @Иван Романов
  «Не точно» — не то слово)  В действительности  выбор знака  зависит от многих факторов, какая уж  точность!  Паузы в этой теме на первом месте,  но мне думается, что паузы вторичны, а главное  — логическое ударение.  Слово "это"? Но оно всего лишь задает грамматику,  при которой необходимо поставить тире. В то же время мы ставим тире и при отсутствии слова "это", что отражено в правилах. Но давайте подождем, что скажут участники форума. Мне тоже интересно.

Comment: Голосуют за запятую, а почему? Ее труднее всего объяснить, да и  в Нацкорпусе она встречается не часто. Может быть, это разговорный вариант? Объясните, пожалуйста.